# Basic Lucene Beginners q: Index and Autocomplete

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.NET and have a basic question:

Do I need to make an additional Index for Autocompletion?
I created an index based on two different tables from a database.

Here are two Docs:

```
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<URL:/Service/Zahlungsmethoden/Teilzahlung>
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<Website:Body:The Text of the first Page>
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<Website:ID:19>
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<Website:Title:Teilzahlung>

stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<URL:/Service/Kundenservice/Kinderbetreeung>
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<Website:Body:The text of the second Page>
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<Website:ID:13>
stored,indexed,tokenized,termVector<Website:Title:Kinderbetreuung>
```

I need to create a dropdown for a search with suggestions:

eg: term "Pag" should suggest "Page"

so I assume that for every word (token) in every doc, I need a list like:

```
p
pa
pag
page
```

is this correct?
Where do I store these?
In an additional Index?

Or how would I re-arrange the existing structure of my index to hold the autocompletion-suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the [Lucene Suggest API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) Like femtoRgon said above, look at the Lucene Suggest API.

2) That being said, one cheap way to perform auto-suggest is to look for all words that start with the string you've typed so far, like 'pa' returning 'pa' + 'pag' + 'page'. A wildcard query would return those results -- in Lucene query syntax, a query like 'pa*'. (You might want to restrict the suggestions to only those strings of length 2+.)

Answer (score 0):

Mark Leighton Fisher has the right approach for a cheap way but performing a wildcard query just returns you the documents but not the words. It's better to look at the imlpementation of the WildcardQuery maybe. You need to use the Terms object retrieved from the IndexReader and iterate through the terms in the index.